# Обмен сообщениями между процессами Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.
Как можно реализовать скрипт на powershell, чтобы увидеть процессы, которые взаимодействуют между собой?

Comment: Какие именно [механизмы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) Вас интересуют?

Comment: @Daemon-5, скорее всего Data Copy